# Tailwindcss styling generated for unused components in React?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

The title pretty much says it all, but I was working on lowering my CSS bundle size for my React Project that uses Tailwindcss, and it seems like CSS is generated for unused components.

My experiment went as follows,
I created a new React Project (Using Vite) installed Tailwindcss using the official guide, created a component in a seperate file called "MyComponent.tsx", with "bg-red-400" className applied, note that the Component is not used in any fashion. Then I did a build and the styling appears to include the "bg-red-400".

I also took a look at the bundled JavaScript which seemed to have a size different depending on whether the component was used or not.

Comment: You configure which files to include in tailwind.comfig.js

Comment: @pguardiario, so if I used a UI Library Tailwind would generate all the styling even for unused components?

Comment: If you use a UI library you would probably import it's styles and tailwind won't scan it unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is intended behaviour.

---

Tailwind generates the CSS at build-time and does not walk your component tree to find out what classes are actually included or not. For once, it's hard to do this in a framework or even language agnostic way (thing className in React vs class in Preact or completely different syntax in frameworks like Vue or Angular). It's also not trivial to know what string ends up being used in a class in the first place.

```
import { clsx } from "clsx";

const Example = () => {
  const myClassName = "bg-red-500";

  return <div className={clsx(myClassName, "p-4")} />;
};
```

This is a fairly harmless example still but you can see how this can become more and more obfuscated especially when libraries like `tailwind-variants` come into play and classes are defined way outside of the scope of a component. And again, this example just looks at React; imagine writing something that has to figure out what ends up being used in a class attribute at some point. Hell, you can even do this with vanilla JS and HTML:

```js
document.getElementById("example").classList.add("px-4");
```

So the point is: Finding out what classes are actually being used is very hard.

So Tailwind goes a simple approach, documented [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth):

> The way Tailwind scans your source code for classes is intentionally very simple — we don’t actually parse or execute any of your code in the language it’s written in, we just use regular expressions to extract every string that could possibly be a class name.

So yes, Tailwind generates all the styling even for unused components because TW has no understanding of what a component is used or not.

Tangent: This also means that classes *in comments* are generated because Tailwind has no understanding of what a comment is.

Comment: Interesting, how do UI libraries deal with this limitation given that they may have hundreds of components with only a few being used, if you know?

Comment: I am not familiar with any UI library that uses Tailwind under the hood but generally UI libraries would have to compile their own stylesheet with TW which would then be consumed by the application (usually with something like `import 'the-library/styles/index.css` or the likes). The library developers could opt to export individual style sheets that can then be imported as needed. Generelly I am not sure the few hundred bytes of css are the bigger issue in modern applications compared to several dozen kilobytes of JavaScript though

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't have hundreds of components available in an app with only a few being used. Alternatively though, what you can do is run Tailwind against your built JS output, that way unused components will be removed, reducing the number of styles.